# Is it possible to get executable file icon by Golang?

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a "Download Page Website", and I trying to show the file icon to my webpage.

Like Windows system, ".exe" file has icon image inside. Or linux executable file. Can I read it?

I know python can do it with a package name "win32api", is it any package for Golang to achieve this function?

Comment: its going to really depend on the platform. do you really only want windows?

Comment: @DanielA.White I made it happen on Windows before.  It's a huge progress for me if I can do this on Linux, because I don't use Windows for server system anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the linux package in your advantage.

For example, you can use `icoextract`, which can be installed via apt:

```
apt install icoextract
```

And then run it like this:

```
icoextract /path/to/file.exe /path/to/file.ico
```

Go make possible to call commands and execute them using the package `os/exec`. So you can do something like

```
func ExtractIcon(executablePath string) []byte {
    file, err := ioutil.TempFile("dir", "prefix")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(file.Name())
    cmd := exec.Command("icoextract", executablePath, file.Name())
    if err = cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(file.Name())
    return content
}
```

Comment: Clever idea! Let me have a try now.